# UIButton selector not called sometimes when initialized from closure

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a bug where sometimes, for certain users, a button press isn't registered.

I have something similar to the following code. This code works fine for me and most people but some of our users don't see anything happen after tapping the button.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let nextButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
        return button
    }()

    @objc fileprivate func handleButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Handle")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(nextButton)
    }
}
```

Changing `nextButton` to a lazy var solves the problem for everyone. I assume this is some problem with self not being fully initialized when `nextButton` is created and that causes the target/selector registration to get messed up.

My question is what could cause this to fail since I can't reproduce the issue myself?

Comment: Really? You can't reproduce the issue? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68205981/what-is-difference-of-self-in-lazy-var-and-varlet-block/68206356).

Comment: I really can't reproduce the issue. The code I posted works as expected.
Your answer does shed light on why it wouldn't work, but now I'm confused why the code works for me.

Comment: What I'm assuming is happening is that the self method is somehow returning nil. Then the button just goes up the responder chain until it finds `handleButtonPressed`. Just need to figure out why that doesn't happen sometimes in my app.

Comment: update the action to .touchUpInside

Comment: To make it work, either use `lazy` or put `addTarget` in your `viewDidLoad` or `init` method. See this post [can't click UIButton inside a cell in UITableview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999822/10158398) too.